# custom react hook returns default value in initial render

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, intersection-observer

I made a hook for `intersection observer` but it is returning state as `false` in initial render and then returning true.
my element is 100% visible to observer but I don't know why it is returning `false` at initial render.
any way to solve this ?

App.js:

```
import React from "react";
import "./App.css";
import useIntersectionObserver from "./hooks/useIntersectionObserver";
const App = () => {
  const Ref = React.useRef(null);
  const { observer, state } = useIntersectionObserver({ rootMargin: "10px" });
  React.useEffect(() => {
    observer.observe(Ref.current);
    console.log(state);
  }, [observer, state]);
  return (
    <>
      <h1 ref={Ref}>Hello World</h1>
      <h3>Text</h3>
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

`useIntersectionObserver` custom hook:

```
import React from "react";

const useIntersectionObserver = ({ options }) => {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(false);
  function callbackfn(entries) {
    entries.forEach(function (entry) {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        setState(true);
      } else {
        setState(false);
      }
    });
  }
  const observer = new IntersectionObserver(callbackfn, options);
  return { observer, state };
};

export default useIntersectionObserver;
```

it will give you this, in console:
[image]

Comment: makes sense right? since the callback function will only be called after things have rendered for the first time but your hook will initially be called before the first render

Comment: @azium can I make it work correctly? and by "callback function" you meant `callbackfn` in my hook ?

Comment: what should be the value of `state` before you call `observer.observe`? I don't think a `boolean` is how you should model this

Comment: what do you mean by work correctly? is something not actually working right now?

Comment: @thedude I tried every scenario possible. it gave me a same result. any solution?

Comment: @azium I don't want it to return `false` at initial render, I want to get true because 100% of an element is visible , so I should get `true` not false.

Comment: you're calling `console.log` directly after passing your ref to the observer - the callback function will only run in the next event loop

Comment: @azium I know, I tried every way I can Imagine to fix this problem and I know before I call `observer` it will give me a `false` state which is default. but I want to fix this. Is there anyway to remodel it ? if there's no way in my code?

Comment: the thing is that nothing is broken from my perspective. it's `false` because you set it to be `false`. it's logging the correct value

Comment: @azium yes it is returning correct value but not the thing I've planned. I wanted to make a hook for my observer and I want a solution to make it possible.

Comment: It seems like you want to force some async behaviour to operate synchronously which is impossible as far as I know. the detault value will always be returned because hooks run synchronously but your `setState ` happens asynchronously

Comment: @azium exactly. because of that I tried other solutions but they didn't work as well. is there any way to remodel it to work the way I want? not by forcing. by new logic

Comment: I don't think it's possible for your default value to update synchronously no - that's just not how intersection observer works

Comment: @azium can I write it differently with different logic? I mean, recreating hook with new logic? I couldn't find out a way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

> 

```js
import React from "react";

const useIntersectionObserver = (options) => {
  const [isInterseting, setInterseting] = React.useState(false);

  const callbackfn = React.useCallback((entries) => {  
    entries.forEach((entry) => {
      if (entry.isIntersecting) {
        setInterseting(true);
      } else {
        setInterseting(false);
      }
    });
  }, [])

  const observer = React.useRef(new IntersectionObserver(callbackFn, options)).current;

  return [observer, {
    isInterseting
  }];
};

export default useIntersectionObserver;
```

Comment: thanks but it is still `false`

Comment: `(2) [IntersectionObserver, {…}]
0: IntersectionObserver {root: null, rootMargin: '0px 0px 0px 0px', thresholds: Array(1), delay: 0, trackVisibility: false}
1: {isInterseting: false}
length: 2
[[Prototype]]: Array(0)`